# How can i count atoms Prolog?

Tags: prolog, logic

how can I solve this problem??

Input:
    count_atoms(T,Count)

Output
     count_atoms(a(b,c(d,e),f),Count).
     Count = 4 ;

I really have no idea... Please can you help me??

Answer (score 1):

using library([aggregate](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%282,%27A.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/aggregate.html%27%29%29)) by SWI-Prolog and recursion:

```
count_atoms(T, Count) :-
       atom(T)
    -> Count = 1
    ;  compound(T)
    -> aggregate_all(sum(C), (arg(_, T, A), count_atoms(A, C)), Count)
    ;  Count = 0
    .
```

test:

```
?- count_atoms(a(b,c(1,e),f),Count).
Count = 3.
```

but I fear this is not the solution for your assignment. For something more basic you could decompose any [compound](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=compound/1) term using [=..](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=%28=..%29/2) and recurse on arguments list.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a stack based approach can help. You could write at least four helper predicates which could look like this:

```
% Increases accumulator if T is atomic + call to count_atoms/6
count_atoms(T, Stack, StackSize, Accumulator, Count) :- ...

% Gets the arity of T if T is compound + call to count_atoms/6
count_atoms(T, Stack, StackSize, Accumulator, Count) :- ...

% Gets Nth subterm of T and puts it on the stack + call to count_atoms/6
count_atoms(T, N, Stack, StackSize, Accumulator, Count) :- ...

% Pops element from stack + call to count_atoms/5
count_atoms(T, _, Stack, StackSize, Accumulator, Count) :- ...
```

But you still need a the count_atoms/2 predicate and one to stop the algorithm and produce the result.